# "Global HttpSession" in java

Tags: java, httpsession

Example, I have 5 different users logged in my application. Each account has a session id saved in my db. But, I want to check if each session Id is active every now and then.

I am planning to create a some sort of global container that holds all the logged in user's session, is this possible? So, when I want to check, I'll just look through the container and check the sessions if active, if not I'll try to create a new one or log out the corresponding user.

If you have any suggestions, I would be willing to listen(read).

Comment: Why? The container will invalidate the session after the idle timeout.

Comment: Couldn't you use any class variable from your controller? or use any table in your db (create one table called global_session)?

Comment: Is this based in an existing framework (like Tomcat or J2EE) or is it something you are writing your self?

Comment: @DiegoPolidoSantana, if I have the table, I could store my session id?
..can I get the session status from the session id? (I'll try to search if this is possible.)

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do if session is inactive?

If you want to logout the user of session is inactive, then just configure session timeout in web.xml

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>5</session-timeout>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

Here the time out is set as 5 mins. After 5 mins of inactivity, the user will be logged out.

Comment: This can be handled by HttpSessionListener sessionDestroyed, right?

Comment: Yes, it can be handled by that method.

Answer (score 0):

Every time the user accesses the session you could store the current time stamp in the database.

To find the inactive sessions you could query for old time stamps.

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine solved my dilemma,

Every session ids from users **were saved in db**, and had **created a session Map**. Only logged in user with valid session ids are in the map; otherwise, they are logged out.

Comment: This is somewhat an integration from EJP and Diego. Thanks.